# Windows Virtual Machine from .VHD

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine

I have virtualised a windows machine using "Disk2VHD" from microsoft sysinternals. I then used Windows virtual machine to create a VM from the .VHD file. I ensured the "Prepare for use in VM" box was checked.

Upon boot I get a "Windows not genuine" error, and the VM will restart.

I've mounted the VHD in diskmgmt, and can access all the information on the disk.

The system i've virtualised is a geniune OEM windows XP Machine. with a 60GB HDD.

Is this a problem of Hardware mis-match?

Comment: Besides the fact  that you shouldn't be using XP in 2018, the OEM license is valid only for the hardware it was sold with. Using the OS in a VM requires another license (and you can't obtain one now for XP anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. OEM licenses are tied to the hardware (the CPU&motherboard) that they were sold on. "License lives and dies with the computer it was originally installed on" to quote a forum post.

- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1963771-licensing-after-virtualizing-windows-xp-physical-machine
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26534530/How-to-Legaly-P2V-an-XP-OEM-Machine.html

(Retail licenses also require hardware check, but *may* be reactivated on a different system a few times. VLK licenses in WinXP aren't bound to the system at all.)

If you have a Retail or VLK key, it might be possible to change the license key on an existing system using [this script from MS Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/328874/how-to-change-the-volume-licensing-product-key-on-a-computer-that-is-r) or [this "key update tool"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=50346&clcid=0x409) (both from Microsoft), although the article doesn't say whether it'll allow changing between different licensing channels.